# Nav se amontona al hacerlo responsive

Tags: html, css

Adjunto mi código:

```css
@font-face { font-family: "mini wakuwaku"; src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/88waz6cgfpoat4o/mini-wakuwaku.otf?dl=0'); format("truetype");}
body{
  font-family: "mini wakuwaku";
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/564x/71/a9/74/71a974d33630b23bc29598538c4d3ea6.jpg") 
}
.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  color: white;
  justify-content:center;
}
.flex-container div a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin:10px;
  font-size:16px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 183, 195);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* border-style:dashed; */
}
.flex-container div a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin:10px;
  font-size:20px;
  background-color: rgb(167, 137, 124);
  padding: 10px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(136, 106, 94);
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* border-style:dashed; */
}

@media (max-width:600px){
  .flex-container{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>sadda</title>
  <meta content="author" content="asdsads">  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible"  content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- q -->
  <link href="estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <div><a href="acerca.html">Acerca de mi</a></div> 
        <div><a href="educacion.html">Educacion</a></div> 
        <div><a href="experiencia.html">Experiencia</a></div> 
        <div><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></div> 
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Me aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Será por el orden que le di? Mi idea es darle más espacio en la parte de abajo. También intenté cambiar el tamaño de la letra de esta forma pero no se cambiaba:

```
@media (max-width:600px){
  .flex-container{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .flex-container div a{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

Si tienen algún otro consejo para que sea más correcto se los agradecería. ¿Está mal que tenga solo un nav y no un header?

Comment: agrega tu html así podemos replicar tu código en nuestros editores

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ listoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes darle un espacio entre la separación de los bloques usando [**`gap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/gap), tu `@media` quedaría así:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
  .flex-container{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    gap: 50px;
  }
}
```